# Calculate occurrence of characters in each loop

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the occurrence of all characters in a for each loop, the base is `inputs`:

```
Object {SchriftEins: "abc ", SchriftZwei: "123"}
```

I'm having this code:

```
//go through every input
$.each(inputs,function(i,el){   
    var schrift = i;
    var string = el;

    // splitt string
    var string_as_array = string.split(""); 

    //count the occurrence of every char        
    $.each(string_as_array,function(i, el){
        // here is the problem:         
        arr[schrift][el] = arr[schrift][el] + 1 || 1;
    });         
    console.log(arr);   
});
```

My problem is, that the calculation is wrong. I assume because of the nested each loop. How can i modify this code to get the right results?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: what is the input and what is expected result?

Comment: The inputs are in the question and the desired results are pretty clear from the code (`arr[schrift][el]`) and description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than splitting strings and using jQuery, you can use the built-in iteration and loop over the string. It is a fair bit simpler and should be *much* faster.

To combine the character counts from every word:

```
var characterCount = {};
Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function (item) {
  var value = inputs[item];
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
    var char = value[i];
    characterCount[char] = (characterCount[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
});
```

Or, separately (as shown in your example):

```
var characterCount = {};
Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function (item) {
  var value = inputs[item];
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
    var char = value[i];

    // This will get existing counts, increment the proper field, and replace.
    // It is a somewhat naive solution and could be improved.
    var counts = characterCount[item] || {};
    counts[char] = (counts[char] || 0) + 1;
    characterCount[item] = counts;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Makaze why would you want to use a `for ... in` loop? There's no advantage and they invite trouble (by potentially iterating over things you don't want to see).

Comment: Interesting... so your method only iterates over user-specified properties as intended? I wouldn't have guessed.

Comment: From the example, `inputs` isn't an array, so `for ... in` would hit every field on the object. That includes methods inherited from the prototype, which you probably don't want. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only lists fields directly assigned to the current object, which tends to be the correct values.